# Why does my CSS button default to a font that has no mention of it anywhere?

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

I’ve been trying to change the font on this button, but it keeps on setting it to the default setting. The code refers to an animated button, and I wish to change the font to "Roboto".

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  font: roboto;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<a button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle" href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en"><span>Instagram</span></button>
```

Comment: did you include the Roboto font file?

Comment: Why are you closing your `<a>` with `</button>`? Neither `text-align: centre` nor `font: roboto;` are valid CSS rules. It’s `text-align: center` and `font-family: Roboto;`. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: The font changes correctly to robot when I remove the "a" from the "<a button class="button"" section, but it stops functioning as a button.

Answer (score 0):

`font: roboto;` won't work - it needs to be `font-familiy: roboto`, and you better add at least one alternative, like `font-familiy: roboto, sans-serif`;

Also watch your HTML: You are opening an`<a>` tag and closing a `</ button>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use font-family instead of font.

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Inserted font-family instead of font */
  font-family: Roboto;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: centre;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<a button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle" href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en"><span>Instagram</span></button>
```